# Documenting/Documentation for Traffic Flow data

Tags: here-api

I've found [bits and pieces of documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/topics/common-acronyms.html) for traffic flow data, but I haven't stumbled on a comprehensive document that includes all of the elements and attributes.  Does such a document exist? If not can you help clarify the definition of some of the attributes and elements below?

```xml
    <RW LI="114+01594" DE="12th Ave" PBT="2019-06-13T16:35:58Z" mid="61fc647b-9e52-41d0-9e18-435ec64b2f8f">
      <FIS>
        <FI><TMC PC="11761" DE="SE Milwaukie Ave/SE Gideon St" QD="-" LE="0.02134"/><CF CN="0.83" FF="13.67" JF="2.00696" SP="8.51" SU="8.51" TY="TR"/></FI>
        <FI><TMC PC="11762" DE="SE Morrison St" QD="-" LE="0.98349"/>
          <CF CN="0.83" FF="21.62" JF="3.41486" SP="10.9" SU="10.9" TY="TR">
            <SSS><SS FF="22.56" JF="2.28167" LE="0.68918" SP="16.38" SU="16.38"/><SS FF="19.68" JF="6.46892" LE="0.2943" SP="8.41" SU="8.41"/></SSS>
          </CF>
        </FI>
        <FI><TMC PC="15730" DE="SE Sandy Blvd" QD="-" LE="0.38267"/><CF CN="0.72" FF="21.81" JF="3.64183" SP="10.41" SU="10.41" TY="TR"/></FI>
        <FI><TMC PC="11763" DE="I-84/US-30/Irving St/NE Lloyd Blvd" QD="-" LE="0.4496"/>
          <CF CN="0.79" FF="23.8" JF="3.21584" SP="12.75" SU="12.75" TY="TR">
            <SSS><SS FF="24.38" JF="3.14159" LE="0.16714" SP="12.11" SU="12.11"/><SS FF="23.44" JF="2.41069" LE="0.28245" SP="16.66" SU="16.66"/></SSS>
          </CF>
        </FI>
      </FIS>
    </RW>
```

- **RW** - Roadway
- **RW@LI** - ?
- **RW@DE** - Looks like the roadway name, but not sure what "DE" translates too.
- **RW@PBT** - The timestamp the resource was requested/computed?
- **RW@mid** - A unique id for the roadway?
- **FIS** - Flow items
- **FI** - Flow item
- **TMC** - [Some sort of region](https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/topics/example-include-tmc-table.html)?
- **TMC@PC** - ?
- **TMC@DE** - Same as RW@DE, but for a segment of the RW?
- **TMC@QD** - Queue direction +/-
- **TMC@LE** - ?
- **CF** - Current flow
- **CF@CN** - Confidence attribute [per this doc](https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/topics/common-acronyms.html)
- **CF@FF** - ?
- **CF@JF** - Jam factor
- **CF@SP** - [Documented here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/topics/common-acronyms.html)
- **CF@SU** - [Documented here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/topics/common-acronyms.html)
- **CF@TY** - ?
- **SSS** - Street segments?
- **SS** - Street segment?
- **SS@FF** - ?
- **SS@JF** - Jam factor
- **SS@LE** - ?
- **SS@SP** - Same as [Documented here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/topics/common-acronyms.html)
- **SS@SU** - Same as [Documented here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/topics/common-acronyms.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see meta resources document page.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/topics/additional-parameters.html

you can request the definition of acronyms based on traffic or incidents api version.

Fro example below request will return a flow xsd.

```
https://traffic.api.here.com/traffic/6.0/xsd/flow.xsd
?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}
&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}
```

Happy coding!